# rails: form not showing checkboxes (not able to parse them?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, strong-parameters

Rails 3.2.12
using strong parameters gem.

I have a form, with checkboxes, after I create. I go to edit, all data is shown Except the checkboxes- which are empty, even though I selected some when created.
The checkboxes data did save in data base- It's there:

```
>> @sender.recipient
=> ["395", "399", "400", ""]
```

but for some reason the form isn't showing it- maybe trouble parsing data since it's array? don't know..

form html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @sender,   html: { class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
...
   <%= f.input :name, label: "name" %>
   <%= f.input :recipient, label: "choose", collection: Member.order("party_id asc, name asc").all, label_method: :name, as: :check_boxes %>
...
<% end %>
```

I suspect the strong parameters is the culprit since it's the first time I'm using it and it's the only (apparently) difference between the other inputs which work fine.

senders_controllers.rb:

```
def create
@sender = Sender.new(sender_params)

if @sender.save
...
else
  render 'new'
end
  end

  def edit
    @sender = Sender.find(params[:id])
  end
  private

  def sender_params
    params.require(:sender).permit(:name, :email, :party, :mail_type, :mail_subject, :mail_content, {:recipient =>[]} )
  end
end
```

notice at sender_params function, at the far right, the recipient part: {:recipient =>[]}

What am I missing?

Thank you very much
I searched the web for a solution but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: I believe the form input should be an association: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: @Gmat, there's no associations here, only normal checkboxes input.
so association won't work.